# const int implicit conversion C++

Tags: c++, casting, constants, const-cast

i'd like to know if there is a sort of implicit conversion between  variables  when using a **pointer to constant integer** , 
for example , if i  use an address of a   variable type  **int**  or **const int**  it accepts to store it , 
however if i use a normal   **pointer to int**  it doesn't allow storing the address of the **const int** type,why is this?, thanks in advance

```
int i=4;
const int ii=4;

//pointer to constant int 
const int *pci=&i; //OK.
pci=&ii; //OK.
int *pi=&ii; //ERROR invalid conversion.
```

Comment: Are you asking for `c++` or `c`? Different languages; Different standards; Different meaning for `const`.

Comment: `int*` could implicitly convert `const int*`, conversely no. In C++.

Comment: Assigning a const pointer to a non-const pointer is wrong. The original was marked as const for a reason, therefore it's considered wrong to just assign it to a non-const pointer. However I think you can achieve what you want with const_cast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first and second assignments initialize `pci` to *constly* point to an `int` or a `const int`.

So you might have one of two situations:

- `const int*` which points to an `int`.

  ```
  pci=&i;
  ```
- `const int*` which points to a `const int`.

  ```
  pci=&ii;
  ```

Both cases are safe because you are only ***adding a constraint***.

By doing:

```
int *pi=&ii;
```

You make an `int*` point to a `const int` which means you ***remove a constraint***.

Since removing a constraint might be risky, this requires you to use a [`const_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast).

```
int* pi = const_cast<int*>(&ii);
```

Note that forcibly removing the `const` modifier is something [you should ask yourself twice if you really wanna do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10498292/c-why-is-const-cast-evil), since it also make the `const` modifier somewhat meaningless because you will be able to modify that *"constant"* address through the converted variable.

Comment: @StoryTeller I'm still confused with that, after all these decades. That may be a reason why I'm avoiding pointers like hell in c++.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, it gets simpler after you down a couple of pints.

Comment: @StoryTeller I'm on it, THX for the hint ;)

Comment: It makes sense. `const` means that "i don't want this to change", right? So it makes sense to prevent it from being assigned to a pointer through which it can be modified. That would defeat the purpose of `const`. However, there are special cases where you may actually want this, hence `const_cast`. So you are allowed to do the conversion after all, but you need to explicitly state it in your code, making it clear what you're doing, which makes your (or your team's) life easier when trying to debug things. It clearly states what's happening, instead of potentially braking things silently.

Comment: @adam10603 There was some saying to read from inner to outer asterisks in a spiral or so ...

Answer (score 1):

Simply assigning a pointer to a `const` element to a pointer to a non-`const` element is not allowed, since that would silently dismiss the `const`-ness of the original, which is something that you don't want, and can also be a source of silent bugs, which is one of the reasons it's not allowed.

However, if this is really what you want, you can explicitly request to remove the `const` qualifier by using [`const_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast)